# Create buttons in html

Tags: javascript, html

My layout has multiple start buttons:

[image]

but they are all generated from one line of code.

Now I want to disable the button that I clicked, ***not all the buttons***.

***Imagine it's a for loop and call button inside.***

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click','.startDocker' ,function(){
        //document.getElementById("startDocker").disabled = true;
        //Run Docker
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'DockerIntegration',
            success: function () {
                alert("sucess");
                document.getElementsByClassName("startDocker").disabled = true;
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
```

Comment: And? What have you tried? What results did you get? What specific question do you have?

Comment: First disable doesn't work. If I do by ID it disables everything , etc... I want to disable the button that I clicked, not all the buttons.

Comment: The callback function takes an event as parameter, you can get the target element (the button in this case) from it.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the clicked button through `$(this)`

```
$(document).on('click','.startDocker' ,function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    //Run Docker
    //...
});
```

Comment: you ignore ajax response ok for change it to disabled, but in esence it is the solution great

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns array of objects, and you have to disable a specific one that you clicked. Try:

```
$(document).on('click','.startDocker' ,function(){
    //document.getElementById("startDocker").disabled = true;
    //Run Docker
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        context: this,
        url: 'DockerIntegration',
        success: function () {
            alert("sucess");
            this[0].disabled = true;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

First you asign `this` context to the ajax function, and then you get the DOM object from jquery object `this[0]`, and set disabled to true.

Answer (score 1):

You should do like below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).on('click', '.startDocker', function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'DockerIntegration',
                    success: function () {
                        alert("sucess");
                        $this.attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });

        });
```

Comment: *"You should do like"* is not a very informative explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.startDocker', function(){
var _button = $(this);
        // document.getElementById("startDocker").disabled = true;
        // Run Docker
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'DockerIntegration',
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
                _button.prop('disabled', true);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: `_button` is a jQuery object not a `HTMLElement` because of that `_button.disabled = true` won't work. Try `var  _button = this;`

Comment: you can change it like @Titus saysor i've ideited fro use JQuery at all

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click','.startDocker' ,function(){
        $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        //document.getElementById("startDocker").disabled = true;
        //Run Docker
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'DockerIntegration',
            success: function () {
                alert("sucess");
                document.getElementsByClassName("startDocker").disabled = true;
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
```

Comment: then do not forgot to accept the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'this' object which holds the object of the button which is clicked to disable it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click','.startDocker' ,function(){
        var $this = this;
        //Run Docker
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'DockerIntegration',
            success: function () {
                alert("sucess");
                $this.disabled = true;
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker">Start</button>
```